# Graphql upsert with condition

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphcms

i'm trying to create a simple leaderboard table, i would like to execute a query to insert or update entry if the new score is higher than the previous one, is it possible to achieve this using graphql ? My upsert mutation look like this

```
mutation addEntry {
  upsertRankentry(
    upsert: {
      create: {id: "111", score: 125110},
      update: {id: "111", score: 125110}}
    where: {id: "111"}
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

edit : I'm using graphCMS to generate my API and i use it in a javascript app with fetch()

Comment: Sure it's possible to have a query that looks like this, it's syntactically valid. How to implement a resolver for this is a totally different question though! You'd need to show us how your backend is implemented if you need help with that.

Comment: I'm simply using graphCMS to generate the API but it's not the point, my problem is that i dont know how to setup conditional update with my mutation. My upsert is updating player score even if the newest score is lower, i would like to update only if the new score value is higher than the one currently stored in the database. Sorry I didn't explain the problem correctly!

Comment: Yes that is the point, this is crucial information! Please [edit] your question to include your current graphcms setup (configuration)

Comment: According to https://graphcms.com/docs/api-reference/content-api/filtering, you should be able to use `where: {id: "111", score_lt: 125110}`

Comment: Thanks for your help! but i got this error : Field \"score_lt\" is not defined by type RankentryWhereUniqueInput. (Rankentry is my model)

Comment: Oh, in that case it might not be possible

Comment: I have to use 2 requests to do what i want i think.. anyway, thanks for your help!